# using async Node.JS to serve HTTP requests

Tags: node.js

I've successfully written a few nodejs HTTP handlers to serve data in response to an HTTP request.  However, everything I've written has been using *Sync version of functions. I'm now quickly running into limitations of this approach.

I cannot figure out, however, how to properly use asynchronous functions in the HTTP request context.  If I try an async call, processing quickly falls through and returns without giving the code a chance to process data.

What's the correct approach?  I haven't been able to find any good examples, so any pointers to literature are appreciated.  Short of that, what's an example of a handler for a GET request that scans a local directory and, say, returns a json list of file names and corresponding number of lines (or really any stub code of the above that shows the proper technique).

Comment: You have to do all of your work in the callbacks to the asynchronous functions

Comment: I know that.  How do I make sure the request handler doesn't return until all callbacks complete (doesn't fall through).

Comment: There are a ton of different ways to do this. I would suggest going with ES7 transpilation + async/await. If you don't want to go through the trouble, then [co](https://github.com/tj/co)/`yield` is pretty close. I would still suggest using  [Promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which are built into node, but the bluebird library I linked can promisify libraries that don't support promises. I highly recommend Promises ... I think they simplify asynchronous flows quite a lot. [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is also popular. Finally, you could roll your own.

Comment: Please show your code that shows what you're trying to do.  The not-so-secret answer here is that you continue the next step after an async operation IN the async callback, not on the next line of code after the async call.

Comment: See a simple node.js server example that uses async I/O in the section of this article titled "Creating simple static file server": http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple sample:

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

function dir (req, res) {
  fs.readdir('.', function (error, files) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(500)
      res.end(error.message)
      return
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      res.write(file + '\n')
    })
    res.end()
  })
}

var server = http.createServer(dir)
server.listen(7000)
```

Run with `node server.js` and test it with `curl :7000`.

Yes the request handler returns before the readdir callback is executed. That is by design. That's how async programming works. It's OK. when the filesystem IO is done, the callback will execute and the response will be sent.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  However, I'm really having a mental block extending this to a more complex case where I have nested levels of async handlers, for example reading contents of each file to count lines and/or doing this for multiple (sub)directories.

Comment: async control flow takes a lot of adjustment from sync code. try nodeschool.io tutorials, callbackhell.com, reading open source projects on github, etc. It will eventually "click".

Answer (score 2):

Peter Lyons' answer is great/correct. I'm going to expand on it a bit and suggest a different method of synchronization using promises and [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) as well as nested/looping asynchronicity.

```
/* Script to count all lines of a file */
const co = require("co");
// Promisifed fs -- eventually node will support this on its own
const fs = require("mz/fs");
const rootDir = 'files/';

// Recursivey count the lines of all files in the given directory and sum them
function countLines(directory) {
    // We can only use `yield` inside a generator block
    // `co` allows us to do this and walks through the generator on its own
    // `yield` will not move to the next line until the promise resolves
    //
    // This is still asynchronous code but it is written in a way
    // that makes it look synchronized. This entire block is asynchronous, so we
    // can `countLines` of multiple directories simultaneously
    return co(function* () {
        // `files` will be an array of files in the given directory
        const files = yield fs.readdir(directory);

        // `.map` will create an array of promises. `yield` only completes when
        // *all* promises in the array have resolved
        const lines = yield files.map(file => countFileLines(file, directory));

        // Sum the lines of all files in this directory
        return lines.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    });
}

function countFileLines(file, directory) {
    // We need the full path to read the file
    const fullPath = `${directory}/${file}`;

    // `co` returns a promise, so `co` itself can be yielded
    // This entire block is asynchronous so we should be able to count lines
    // of files without waiting for each file to be read
    return co(function* () {
        // Used to check whether this file is a directory
        const stats = yield fs.stat(fullPath);
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            // If it is, recursively count lines of this directory
            return countLines(fullPath);
        }
        // Otherwise just get the line count of the file
        const contents = yield fs.readFile(fullPath, "utf8");
        return contents.split("\n").length - 1;
    });
}

co(function* () {
  console.log(yield countLines(rootDir));
})
// All errors propagate here
.catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
```

Note that this is just an example. There are probably already libraries to count lines of files in a directory and there are definitely libraries that simplify recursive reading/globbing of files.

Comment: holy cow!  I've been doing JavaScript on and off for... pretty much since its beginning, but it looks like during the last off-on period the language has undergone an awesome mutation.